# Image coloured hover over overflowing

Tags: css

Just a simple image that uses some jQuery to fade some content over the top when moused over.
Only problem is that when the hover over takes effect, the hover spills into the div gutter making the hover over bigger than the actual container.

each image is layed out like so

```
<li class="large-4 columns item">
<div class="description"><h1>Image hover</h1><a href="#"></a></div>
<img class="display" src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
</li>
```

Can see a live example here.
http://jsfiddle.net/QLUMH/

Any ideas on ways to fix/improve what I am doing here? Cheers

Comment: Its not going out the container the default image is small in width than the hover one. but the container(li) is have the width of entire screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your description fills the entire column, which is wider than your image. If you add an "inner column"/container that collapse to the same width as your image, it will work alright. I've created [a fork of your demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yTmF7/) that demonstrates this.

I've added a wrapper "ib" (Just stands for inner block. rename this to a proper name) inside each .column.item like so:

```
<div class="ib">
    <div class="description">
       <h1>Image hover</h1><a href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <img class="display" src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
</div>
```

And then just created a very simple CSS rule for making this wrapper collapse to its contents:

```
.ib {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Just what I needed thanks, I tried a similar approach, but didn't quite work so thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/QLUMH/1/)

Here you have live example,
you are giving 100% to width and height.
so that really goes overflow.

Code edited-

```
#portfolio .description {
        position: absolute;
        background: rgba(0,199,134,0.8);
        display: none;
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change in CSs will help,

I have updated the same in [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/QLUMH/2/)

with change in CSS,

```
#portfolio .description {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0,199,134,0.8);
    display: none;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}

#portfolio .description h1 {
    color: white;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20%;
width:400px;
height:300px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Update:

If the `H1` created extra cutter and wrapping issue(for some), please use the `DIV` tag instead, which should work fine!

I hope this will solve your problem :)

Comment: Sorry, I should of added that this is a fluid grid, so the content is purposely expanded to 100% to fill the container, however it continues to jump into the gutter between containers.

Comment: Note: only changing of .description will not help.

Comment: setting a div to position:absolute removes it from any container that is not also positioned, therefore if you set the width to 100% - in this case - it will take the entire width of your page. As the two others have stated, you must also use absolute heights and widths in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You did not style your `li`. The issue is that in foundation.css it is getting `padding-left` and `padding-right`. You need to remove that and use `margin-left` and `margin-right` instead. And you also need to fix the width of the `li`. As `.description` will get its 100% height. So you need to include a small css in your own file (don not modify foundation.css).

```
#portfolio li.columns{
    /* You can use the width in '%' if you want to make the design fluid */
    width: 400px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0.9375em;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QLUMH/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll just have to get rid of the padding on tne `li`

`li{ padding:0 }`

or use the the [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing) property:

`li { box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; }